# Concatenate values in one row with comma as delimiter in TABLEAU worksheet

Tags: concatenation, tableau-api

Currently my sheet looks like:

```
Type | Product 
A    | p1
B    | p2
A    | p2
C    | p3
```

I want my sheet to look like:

```
Type | Product 
A    |p1,p2
B    |p2
C    |p3
```

I want to show all products of Type 'A' in one row. To avoid duplicates 'A' entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a couple table calculations to do this:

create 1 named Products:

```
IF  INDEX() = 1
THEN ATTR([Product])
ELSE
PREVIOUS_VALUE(ATTR([Product]))+ ", "+ ATTR([Product])END
```

This needs to be set to compute using pane down

Then create another called Rank

```
RANK([Products])
```

Put Type, Rank (you will need to change this to discreet to put between type and product), and your original Product field into your Rows.

Right click on your "Rank" and "Product" fields in the row and deselect "Show Header"
put "Rank" into your filters and set it to only be the value of "1"

You will then need to right click on Rank and set it to Calculate using "Pane(across then down)"

Put your new "Products" measure into your text mark.

With this you should get a sheet that looks like this:
[image]